# How can i store the gemini model chat history of each chat

Tags: python, database, chat, chatbot, google-gemini

Brief description:
what I want is for the user to create multiple chats, and also be able to continue the previous conversation.
In the below code to continue with `chat1` in `chat3` I need a history how I can I store that history so that I can use it when I require it?

```
import os
import google.generativeai as genai

GOOGLE_API_KEY = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_API_KEY')

genai.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')

chat1 = model.start_chat(history=[])
response = chat1.send_message("Which is asia's largest country?")
response1 = chat1.send_message("What about it's capital?")
response2 = chat1.send_message("What about it's population?")
for message in chat1.history:
    print(f'**{message.role}**: {message.parts[0].text}')

print("*"*50)

chat2 = model.start_chat(history=[])
response = chat2.send_message("Which is india's capital?")
response1 = chat2.send_message("What about it's population?")
for message in chat2.history:
    print(f'**{message.role}**: {message.parts[0].text}')

print("*"*50)

chat3 = model.start_chat(history=chat1.history)
response = chat3.send_message("what's the name of it's currency?")
for message in chat3.history:
    print(f'**{message.role}**: {message.parts[0].text}')
```

I want the ways how can i store the chat history.

**Note**:I'm using django as framework and mysql as DB

Answer (score 0):

I don't have details about your application, but perhaps you don't need multiple chats but rather multiple histories. I had a similar problem and what I did to solve this problem was store a history per user and pass it to each call, f.e:

```
genai.configure(api_key = gkey)
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro', generation_config=generation_config)
history_clients = {}

def start_chat(context, user):
  if user not in history_clients:
    history_clients[user] = []
  
  answer, error = None, None
  try:
    chat = model.start_chat(history=history_clients[user])
    chat.send_message(context)
    history_clients[user] += chat.history

    answers = [message.parts[0].text for message in chat.history if message.role == "model"]
    answer = answers [-1]
  
  except Exception as e:
    error = f'error: {e}'
  
  return answer, error
```

In my case a just wanted the last answer from my chat.history

So you can access by

```
answer, error = start_chat(message.content, message.author.id)
if erro:
   print(erro)
else:
   print(resposta)
```